# Database of horse racing results?

Tags: horse-racing

Is there such a thing as a worldwide repository of horse racing results? I have looked around but only found sites that specialise in one or two countries at most (e,g, [proform racing](http://www.proformracing.com) for UK and Ireland).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this service can be useful for you:

http://www.horseracingintfed.com/default.asp?section=Racing&area=0

Is a query form about horse racing, or you want a direct access on this database?

Comment: Not bad, though it only has group races and only records the first three finishers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple which are mainly USA. They do have race information from around the world, particularly if a horse is entering a Kentucky Derby prep race or other big graded stakes event:

1. [Equibase.com](https://www.equibase.com)
2. [Brisnet.com](https://www.brisnet.com)
3. [DRF.com](https://www.drf.com)

[Source Cited](https://www.sportsbetting3.com/kentucky-derby-betting)